# How can I change the shape of an existing array while keeping the contents centered and fill the new spaces with 0's?

Tags: python

I create a numpy matrix using this line of code:

`map = np.random.randint(3, size=(7, 7))`

How can I change the shape of the matrix to be a 9x9 matrix, while still keeping the contents in the matrix? I'd like the contents to be centered in the 9x9 matrix.

As per comment request, here is an example of an initial matrix, followed by the desired output.

Initial:

```
[[1 2 1 1 2 2 1]
 [1 0 2 2 0 2 0]
 [2 0 2 1 1 0 2]
 [2 2 2 2 0 1 2]
 [1 1 2 1 0 0 1]
 [2 2 1 1 1 2 1]
 [1 2 0 0 2 2 0]]
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 0]
 [0 1 0 2 2 0 2 0 0]
 [0 2 0 2 1 1 0 2 0]
 [0 2 2 2 2 0 1 2 0]
 [0 1 1 2 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 0]
 [0 1 2 0 0 2 2 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

As you can see, the initial matrix is centered within the new 9x9 matrix.

Comment: `map1 = np.zeros((9,9), dtype=int)` and then `map1[1:8,1:8] = map`

Comment: Best not to use `map` as variable name as it's a built-in function of python. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: @ScootCork Good point.

Comment: @alaniwi, your solution works! Thank you!

Comment: @ScootCork thanks, I'll change it.

Comment: @lionrocker221 I could have used (a bit more generally) `[1:-1, 1:-1]` instead of `[1:8, 1:8]` i.e. where `1: -1` means from the second to the second last.

Comment: There is also a [`numpy.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) function, which does the trick.

Comment: For really big matrix, it *might* be marginally more efficient to use `np.empty` instead of `np.zeros` (uninitialised data), and then just zero some slices around the edges, rather than zero all the memory only to overwrite most of it. But the difference is probably pretty marginal (no pun intended...)

Comment: @alaniwi my matrix is just going to stay 9x9 for now so using np.empty may not be necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create your 7x7 matrix:

```
map7 = np.random.randint(2, size=(7, 7))
```

Then if you want all zeros around in 9x9 matrix use:

```
map9 = np.zeros((9,9), dtype=int)
```

Then place your matrix inside the newly created matrix

```
map9[1:8,1:8] = map7
```